# jquery content slider

Tags: jquery, slider

this content slider works fine in IE8, and i just tested on FF with FireBug 1.5 and could not find why it doesnt work in FireFox... can anyone else find why its not working in FF?

https://www.bcidaho.com/about_us/reduce-healthcare-costs.asp

Answer (score 1):

Change the z-index of .contentslider to 1, instead of -100. When i made that change in FireBug, the slider worked perfectly.

Comment: that did not work.  i just checked it on FF 3.5.8 on a Mac and still the same thing.. when i hover over the arrow, it does nothing.  And when i did that in IE8 it put my drop down menu behind the content slider... dang it..

Comment: looks like you changed it to -1, not 1

Comment: I put it back to -1 after i realized 1 would put the menu behind the content slider... sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: btw, you have the .contentslider class in 2 places in global.css, when you make these changes, are you changing both classes? perhaps you should remove one of them

Comment: I see the issue in IE8. I tried it without the z-index on .contentslider, and it worked in both IE8 and Firefox (but i had to make sure to edit both classes)

Comment: update on above. while the class is duplicated, the css in each class isnt, so thats not the problem. however, it looks like global.css is being linked to twice somewhere, and that seems to be causing some issues in firefox.

Comment: also tested in Chrome, doesnt work with the z-index, but removing it helps there as well. btw, global.css is being imported from both home.css and stakeholders.css, which seems to cause the issue i mentioned.